# Comparing strings from a written file

Tags: java, sorting, methods, filewriter

I'm stuck on this program I'm making for school. Here's my code:

```
public static void experiencePointFileWriter() throws IOException{

    File writeFileResults = new File("User Highscore.txt");

    BufferedWriter bw;

    bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(writeFileResults, true));

    bw.append(userName + ": " + experiencePoints);
    bw.newLine();
    bw.flush();
    bw.close();

    FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(writeFileResults);

    char[] a = new char[50];
    fileReader.read(a); // reads the content to the array
    for (char c : a)
        System.out.print(c); // prints the characters one by one
    fileReader.close();

}
```

The dilemma I'm facing is how can I sort new scores with the scores in writeFileResults by the numerical value of int experiencePoints? If you're wondering about the variables userName is assigned by a textfield.getText method, and an event happens when you press one of 36 buttons which launches a math.Random statement with one of 24 possible outcomes. They all add different integer numbers to experiencePoints.

Comment: What is the type of variable `oldScores`?

Comment: Also, I think you are going to want to read in all scores in to memory and sort them then write them all back to the file (as the simplest approach).

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't want to do your homework, and this does seem introductory so I'd like to give you some hints.

First, there's a few things missing:

1. We don't have some of the variables you've given us, so there is no type associated with `oldScores`
2. There is no reference to `userName` or `experiencePoints` outside this method call

If you can add this information, it would make this process easier. I could infer things, but then I might be wrong, or worse yet, have you learn nothing because I did your assignment for you. ;)

EDIT:

So, based on extra information, you're data file is holding an "array" of usernames and experience values. Thus, the best way (read: best design, not shortest) would be to load these into custom objects then write a comparator function (read: implement the abstract class [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html)).

Thus, in pseudo-Java, you'd have:

1. Declare your data type:

   ```
   private static class UserScore {
       private final String name;
       private final double experience;
       // ... fill in the rest, it's just a data struct
   }
   ```
2. In your reader, when you read the values, split each line to get the values, and create a new `List<UserScore>` object which contains all of the values read from the file (I'll let you figure this part out)
3. After you have your list, you can use [Collections#sort](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29) to sort the list to be the correct order, here would be an example of this:

   ```
   // assuming we have our list, userList
   Collections.sort(userList, new Comparator<UserScore>() { 
       public int compare(UserScore left, UserScore right) {
           return (int)(left.getExperience() - right.getExperience()); // check the docs to see why this makes sense for the compare function
       }
   }
   // userList is now sorted based on the experience points
   ```
4. Re-write your file, as you see fit. You now have a sorted list.

Comment: No offense, but my assignment has about 1200 lines of code and this is one tiny method within it. It's hardly finishing my homework if you help me with one method. userName is assigned by a textfield.getText method, and an event happens when you press one of 36 buttons which launches a math.Random statement with one of 24 possible outcomes. They all add different integer numbers to experiencePoints depending.

Comment: It seems like there is supposed to be an array of data here, but you just said there is one value? If that's the case, what is being sorted? Just looking for clarification.

Comment: The user along with the score the user attained needs to be sorted compared to other user's names with their user scores. This method writes to the file and I need some way to sort the high scores in a written file. For example, if a user named "Steve" gets the score 155, and user "Paul" who has a score of 130 was the last user to play, I need some way to make my program recognize Steve's score was higher than Paul's and print Steve's above Paul's in the written file. And thank you for responding to this thread by the way.

Comment: Edited the original post with a pseudo-Java solution.. which basically just left out stuff I was too lazy to write in the silly StackOverflow editor

Comment: Yes and no, you probably want ArrayList here, but no matter which you choose, your object that you hold reference to should be of the type of the interface (`List<UserScore>`) rather than `ArrayList<UserScore>`.

Comment: Getting this error when I try to use array lists: 

The method sort(List<T>, Comparator<? super T>) in the type Collections is not applicable for the arguments (ArrayList<String>, Comparator<scoreList>) 

// I assigned the two as: 

ArrayList<String> scoreList = new ArrayList <String>();

//and
  
ArrayList<String> userList = new ArrayList <String>();

Sorry in advance for my incessant questions.

Comment: You need to create a class which implements `Comparator<String>`. The one I wrote should work for you, but if it doesn't, you can easily [write your own](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html). Side note, use back-ticks (`) to put code in-line.